# AWS Java SDK: Cannot find symbol: method EndpointConfiguration(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven

Super rusty in Java here

Trying to contribute to an open source project that uses maven and aws

As per what I believe is the [right page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration.html) in the doc, I start with

`import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration;`

Then I define a variable

`EndpointConfiguration end_point;`

But I get the error

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method EndpointConfiguration(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: class repository.AmazonS3Client
```

I had a bug with import statement earlier but I fixed that by adding

`"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.975"`

to the Scala SBT file

Am I doing the java import wrong? Do I need to import another package in the SBT? I couldn't find anything else on the Maven repository

I've tried static import as well. Didn't work

Comment: Is the necessary jar added to your build-path?

Comment: I dont think I know enough to answere that question. I will ask the project devs. Thank you